# Copy assign json-Container to vector

Tags: c++, json, assign, assignment-operator

I am trying to convert a `json`-Container from the JSON-library [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)  to a `vector`, but it does not work with the `=`-operator (I get a compiler error "more than one operator "=" matches these operands").

A minimum working example:

```
#include "json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> v = { 0 , 10 , 20 , 100 };
    json j(v);

    vector<double> copy = j;

    vector<double> copyWithAssign;
    //copyWithAssign = j; // more than one operator "=" matches these operands

    return 0;
}
```

You can find the json.hpp [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/src/json.hpp).

Using the constructor with `vector<double> copy = j;` works and I could write  `copyWithAssign = copy;` but that seems dumb. There must be a direct way to assign `j` to a `vector` which has been declared and constructed before.

I thought casting might help since the compiler can't decide which type to use. I tried `(vector<double>)j`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Please do not link to a download link.  Panic ensues.

Comment: I can easily remove the link but I want readers to be able to run my minimum working example as easy as possible. How can I do this after I removed the link? (By the way, why is it bad to post the download link to a header-file?)

Comment: Just because it says it is a header file does not mean it is.  You can link to the text, and then if people want it they can chose to download it or copy it into their own file.  For instance [this link](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/src/json.hpp) links to the source without downloading

Comment: So linking to the homepage of the project on GitHub is okay? But I shouldn’t link the header file because it could be a security issue? Well, I will remove it then, but I don’t really see why linking a header file on the project page is an issue. (I checked it of course.)

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I didn’t get what you wanted.

Comment: No problem.  It's fine to link to the file.  It's just that a file download sounds off alarm bells, especially when not expecting to download anything.  see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296795/should-direct-download-links-be-removed-from-a-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should use

```
copyWithAssign = j.get<vector<double>>();
```

Credits go to theodelrieu who posted this answer [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/635#issuecomment-310686247).